# Windows equivalent for spawning and killing separate process group in Python 3?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.5

I have a web server that needs to manage a separate multi-process subprocess (i.e. starting it and killing it).

For Unix-based systems, the following works fine:

```
# save the pid as `pid`
ps = subprocess.Popen(cmd, preexec_fn=os.setsid)

# elsewhere:
os.killpg(os.getpgid(pid), signal.SIGTERM)
```

I'm doing it this way (with `os.setsid`) because otherwise killing the progress group will also kill the web server.

On Windows these `os` functions are not available -- so if I wanted to accomplish something similar on Windows, how would I do this?

I'm using Python 3.5.

Comment: You can create a new process group via `ps = subprocess.Popen(cmd, creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP)`. The group ID is the process ID of the lead process. That said, it's only useful for processes in the tree that are attached to the same console (conhost.exe instance) as your process, if your process even has a console. In this case, you can send the group a Ctrl+Break via `ps.send_signal(signal.CTRL_BREAK_EVENT)`. Processes shouldn't ignore Ctrl+Break. They should either exit gracefully or let the default handler execute, which calls `ExitProcess(STATUS_CONTROL_C_EXIT)`.

Comment: @eryksun thank you for your answer. I should have clarified, I'm using Python 3.5, and it doesn't look like that flag is available anymore.

Comment: Ah silly me, it's just not available because I ran it on my Linux machine. I'll try it on Windows -- thank you!

Answer (score 5):

**THIS ANSWER IS PROVIDED BY [eryksun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205580/eryksun) IN COMMENT. I PUT IT HERE TO HIGHLIGHT IT FOR SOMEONE MAY ALSO GET INVOLVED IN THIS PROBLEM**。

Here is what he said:

> You can create a new process group via ps = subprocess.Popen(cmd, creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP). The group ID is the process ID of the lead process. That said, it's only useful for processes in the tree that are attached to the same console (conhost.exe instance) as your process, if your process even has a console. In this case, you can send the group a Ctrl+Break via ps.send_signal(signal.CTRL_BREAK_EVENT). Processes shouldn't ignore Ctrl+Break. They should either exit gracefully or let the default handler execute, which calls ExitProcess(STATUS_CONTROL_C_EXIT)

I tried it with this and succeed:

```
process = Popen(args=shlex.split(command), shell=shell, cwd=cwd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE,creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP)
/*...*/
process .send_signal(signal.CTRL_BREAK_EVENT)
process .kill()
```

Comment: Yow seem to have several undefined variables in your solution, can you please include the definitions of these? (command, shell, cwd, PIPE, signal)