# Python: kill subprocess does not work (wrong PID)

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to start a .exe from a Python program, let it run for a couple of seconds and then kill it. I'm using the `subprocess` library. Here's what I did (in short):

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen('start /b .\ssf.exe', shell=True)
time.sleep(5)
p.terminate()
```

I also tried `p.kill()`, but without any luck.

Also, when I `print(p.pid)`, it's a different PID than the one I find in the processes list... Can someone tell me why this is not working?

Answer (score 4):

You didn't start `ssf.exe` in a subprocess. You started a subprocess that would start `ssf.exe` in *yet another* process. When you run `p.terminate()`, you're terminating the middleman, not `ssf.exe`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import os
import signal
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen('start /b .\ssf.exe', shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
time.sleep(5)
os.killpg(os.getpgid(p.pid), signal.SIGTERM)
```

Comment: I found that solution here on Stackoverflow as well but it does not work for me: `AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'killpg'`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/how-to-terminate-a-python-subprocess-launched-with-shell-true

Comment: I tried adding "exec" in front of my command but that doesn't start the exe at all: `exec start /b .\ssf.exe`

Comment: How do you run it in the shell? python verision ? windows or linux?

Comment: When I open command prompt in the same folder as the ssf.exe, I just type .\ssf.exe and it runs the program. The reason I added `start /b` is because I didn't want it to open a new command prompt.

Comment: Remove start /b and try, and add preexec_fn=os.setsid to subprocess options

Comment: Error: `AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'setsid'`

Comment: my bad. on windows os functionalities are not availble, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47016723/windows-equivalent-for-spawning-and-killing-separate-process-group-in-python-3

Comment: So what should I try now?

Comment: Your python version?

Comment: Python version 3.6

Comment: I tried the solution in the link you sent but I get this error: `SystemError: <class 'OSError'> returned a result with an error set`

Comment: Is it possible to just kill a process based on its name? The process is called ssf.exe and there's no other process called like that.

Comment: Found it: `os.system("taskkill /f /im ssf.exe")`

Comment: import psutil

PROCNAME = "ssf.exe"

for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    # check whether the process name matches
    if proc.name() == PROCNAME:
        proc.kill()

Answer (score 1):

I figured that killing the process was the easiest:

```
os.system("taskkill /f /im ssf.exe")
```